# How do i create my own cryptocurrency?

Tags: development, ripple, altcoin, currencies, altcoin-development

There are any guidelines about how to create my own currency from Ripple?

Comment: Check here https://github.com/ripple and fork it to start with.

Comment: @asterisk I have already checked this, but there are lots of libraries, Would you please specify the library?